# Azure Workbook: "This item could not be restored" even though i copied template provided by Azure

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-cli, azure-monitor-workbooks

Imported ARM template with Workbook item cannot be accessed because:

> **This item could not be restored.**

> Could not find Workbook with id /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/SomeGroup/providers/microsoft.insights/workbooks/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111 in subscription 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000. It may have been deleted or moved, or you may not have access to it.

Workbook was crated on Azure Portal, works fine, and its ARM template stored in json file.
When I use *Deploy a custom template* in Portal or Azure CLI

```
az deployment group create -n WorkbookName -g SomeGroup --template-file workbook.json
```

it passes. But when I try to enter it (the workbook in Resource groups) and peek a result (after clicking **Open Workbook**) I end up with above error.

My role is **Contributor**, so I don't think this is a problem with access.

Answer (score 1):

This limitation no longer applies, there's no restriction on the workbook type being deployed inside application insights (starting 3/24/2021).

see: https://github.com/microsoft/Application-Insights-Workbooks/blob/master/Documentation/LegacyAI/LegacyWorkbooksConversion.md

for concrete details.

Answer (score 0):

The error is misleading in this case and, in my opinion, there should be some kind of error during template deployment.

For the moment of writing this answer there is still a [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-automate#limitations) regarding Workbook and its not-copy-paste (directly into Workbook's gallery template) deployment:

> For a technical reason, this mechanism cannot be used to create workbook instances in the *Workbooks gallery* of Application Insights. We are working on addressing this limitation. In the meanwhile, we recommend that you use the Troubleshooting Guide gallery (workbookType: `tsg`) to deploy Application Insights related workbooks.

You can find your newly created Workbook in you *Resource groups* tab.

Comment: FYI, this limitation is literally changing starting today (3/24/2021).  if you create workbooks inside application insights via template, you should be able to see them.  if you can't, feel free to mail me directly, [first letter of first name][lastname] at microsoft.

Comment: @JohnGardner Indeed, I could create a workbook with `workbook` value and it appeared in _gallery_. Thanks for the info. I suppose it has something to do with recent [Application Insights Workbooks Conversion](https://github.com/microsoft/Application-Insights-Workbooks/blob/master/Documentation/LegacyAI/LegacyWorkbooksConversion.md).