# How to create workbooks for App Services in Application Insights using ARM Template?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-rm-template, azure-monitor-workbooks

I have created "New Failure Analysis" workbooks for Azure App Services using Azure Portal and then deployed the Dashboard using an ARM Template by referring to the workbooks.

But, I want to create workbooks using ARM templates for Azure App Services. Is there any automation process for deploying workbooks in Azure Application Insights?

Comment: Yes, you can deploy workbooks in Azure Application Insights using ARM template. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/69844804/15969115, https://stackoverflow.com/a/66580994/15969115 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/67306613/15969115

Answer (score 1):

The details for [deploying workbooks as ARM templates are in Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-automate#azure-resource-manager-template-for-deploying-a-workbook-instance)

For the specific point question about "for azure app services", the resource that the workbook/template is linked to is the `workbookSourceId` parameter of the template in the azure docs, or the `properties.sourceId` field in the content.  To link a workbook to an app service, that field would be the azure resource id value for the app service.

Unfortunately, App Services doesn't currently have a "Workbooks" menu item, and we're trying to get the App Services team to add it.

However, that doesn't prevent you from saving workbooks *linked* to an app service, it just limits you from finding them inside the resource itself.  you'd still be able to find and open them by using the full Workbooks resource type browse experience (like all resources have)